# Баг профиля на мете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Если в профиле на мете ruSO перейти по ссылке "в лучших XXX за YYY", то эта надпись становится нечитаемой. В профиле на ruSO/enSO/meta.enSO (скорее всего и на других подсайтах) баг не наблюдается.

Шаги воспроизведения:

1. Открываем профиль пользователя на мете (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=profile)
2. Смотрим на ссылку "в лучших XXX за YYY" рядом с ником (белая надпись на синем фоне)
3. Переходим по этой ссылке "в лучших XXX за YYY"
4. Открываем профиль пользователя на мете (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=profile)
5. Смотрим на ссылку "в лучших XXX за YYY" рядом с ником (нечитаемая серая надпись на синем фоне)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.top-badge a {
    color: white;
}
```

Заменить на

```
.top-badge a, .top-badge a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```