# Баг со знаками в профиле

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки

Со [знаками в профиле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=badges) та же проблема, что и в [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2704/5079): при переходе по ссылке знака текст на знаке становится нечитаемым:

[image: нечитаемая метка]

Проблема со стилями знаков встречается во всех местах:

- [профиль](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=profile) - внизу страницу
- [активность](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=topactivity) - блок "знаки"
- [полученные знаки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh?tab=badges)
- [информация по конкретному знаку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/55/fanatic?userid=5079)
- [справка по знакам](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)
- и т.д.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1395/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну так закрывать значит надо

Comment: тут подробнее описано. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на главной на мете "Недавно полученные знаки" - то же самое.